# Get table sizes without SELECT permission

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

I want a scheduler to run a simple SQL script to collect the sizes of tables in our MySQL database:

```
SELECT table_name, data_length, index_length
FROM information_schema.TABLES
```

The user the scheduler logs in as has very limited privileges:

```
GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'our-user'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'
```

This is intentional - we don't want the user to access any data; only metadata such as table sizes.

From the MySQL manual I thought those permissions should suffice. In particular, that's what it has to say about `information_schema.*` tables:

> Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges.

but then adds

> These restrictions do not apply for InnoDB tables; you can see them with only the PROCESS privilege.

Our tables *are* InnoDB tables.

Still, when running the script under `our-user`, I only get the system tables (`TABLES`, `VIEWS`, `INNODB_*`) listed. The same script does show our user tables when run by a different user with `SELECT` permission for our tables.

From the manual it also follows that VIEWS can be run with the privileges of creator, so I tried wrapping my query in a view:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW view_table_sizes AS <the query above>
```

However, when this view is SELECTed from by `our-user`, only the system tables are returned. Needless to say, the view was created by a privileged user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite what you asked for:

```
-- As root:
GRANT EXECUTE, PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'se129148'@'localhost' 
    IDENTIFIED BY  'se129148';

use test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE se129148 ()
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SELECT table_name, data_length, index_length
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE table_schema = 'test'
        LIMIT 5;
END //
DELIMITER ;

-- As se129148:
CALL se129148();

+------------+-------------+--------------+
| table_name | data_length | index_length |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 07         |           0 |         1024 |
| 597377b    |           0 |         1024 |
| abbrevstmt |    25739264 |      2637824 |
| adjprice   |         400 |         1024 |
| altc       |       16384 |            0 |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Note that I had to add `EXECUTE` permission.

Alternatively:

```
-- as root:
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE se129148b ()
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'abbrevstmt';
END //
DELIMITER ;

-- as se129148:
mysql> CALL se129148b();
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--
--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name       | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | A
uto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--
--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| abbrevstmt | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 53379 |            482 |    25739264 |               0 |      2637824 |   5242880 |
      5413815 | 2014-03-05 10:02:21 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--
--------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
    | Grants for se129148@localhost
    | GRANT EXECUTE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'se129148'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...' |
```

Note: EXECUTE, not PROCESS.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, this worked!
And actually this is pretty much what I asked for, as I was able to wrap that query in a stored procedure, then give the user permission to execute only that SP.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) that fires every 15 minutes. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/).

The `EVENT` could be used to populate a table with the necessary information.

Then [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) SELECT on that table and only that table to your user.

Comment: Thanks @vérace! This does sound like a solution. At the moment I'm having troubles enabling events in our Amazon RDS MySQL instance, but I'll be sure to get back once I've figured that out.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like enabling EVENTs in RDS would be too much pain in our case, involving restart of the production DB which we never normally do.
That being said, that's an interesting idea and would probably work for someone in a 'normal' MySQL instance.